# Как правильно добавить репозиторий в ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

У меня есть centOS. И для его раскатки написан такой ansible скрипт:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
          - name: set vm.max_map_count
            sysctl: name=vm.max_map_count value=262144 state=present

          - name: ensure all interfaces are up
            service: name=network enabled=yes state=restarted

          - name: install docker
            yum: name=docker-1.10.3 state=latest
```

Проблема в том, что изначально в `yum` репозиториях нет докера. Такая задача не помогает:

```
  - name: add docker repository to yum 
    yum_repository:
            name: docker-ce
            description: docer-ce repository
            baseurl: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

Возникает проблема с ключами `GPG`:

```
Alternatively you can specify the url to the key you would like to use
for a repository in the 'gpgkey' option in a repository section and yum
will install it for you.

For more information contact your distribution or package provider.
```

Как организовать установку докера правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Модуль [yum_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/yum_repository_module.html) поддерживает работу с ключами:

```
- name: Add the YUM Docker repository.
  yum_repository:
    name: docker
    description: Docker Repository
    baseurl: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
    gpgkey: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg
    gpgcheck: yes
```

Comment: Не работает. При таком задании репозитория и последующей установке докера (`sudo yum install docker-ce`) получаю: `https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.`

Comment: В `baseurl` надо наверное писать `https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/$basearch/stable`.

Answer (score 1):

Я так добавляю, PGP не спрашивает

```
- name: Add docker repository
  get_url:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/docer-ce.repo
  become: yes
```